# Retrieve each value of sharedpreference in a adapter

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences, android-adapter

I'm trying to retrieve each value stored in a sharedpreference variable. I use a listview where to display all the values stored in a sharedpreference var. Those values are urls from internet that point to different images that are displayed in the listview.
What a i want to do is how to display each value of the sharedpreference in the listview through the adapter i did. My code of the getView in the Adapter class is :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // reference to convertView
    View v = convertView;

    // inflate new layout if null
    if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listado_imagenes_subidas, null);
    }

    // load controls from layout resources
    ImageView imagen = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    Button botonCopiarUrl = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnCopiarImagenUrl);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);

    // set data to display
    imagen.setImageDrawable(sharedPreferences.getString("url", ""));

    // return view
    return v;
}
```

With this code i only get the first value of the sharedpreferences all the time regardless of the number of items i have in the listview.
Could you please help me with this issue?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: How dit you store the other urls? You should have told us ofcourse. You could use "url0", "url1", "url2", "url3". And retrieve with `...getString("url" + position, "")`.

Comment: I store the urls with url and then the url value, like "url", url value; "url",url value; "url", url value;etc.

Comment: Then you have only one key value pair. Only the last one remains. Do it as i proposed. It is very strange that you did not comment on it.

Comment: No, i have many pairs of keys with the same key "url". Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you ask? `Then you have only one key value pair`. And you have seen it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting only one value from sharedpreferences because you are trying to get only a single value you can create a loop to get other values

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to encrypt all stored Strings, that should give everything you need.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyApp.getAppContext());

    Map<String, ?> all = prefs.getAll();
    String key, value;
    for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : all.entrySet()) {
        key = entry.getKey();
        if(entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
            value = (String) entry.getValue();

            // encrypt and store again
        }      
    }
```

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: ah, maybe i missunderstood your question, if you only have this single "url" preference, it will make no sense to iterate through all your preferences. You can only store single values for one key (e.g. "url")

Comment: With your script, the listview will display in each row each value item stored in sharedpreference? or do i have to program something that dinamically retrieve the value of a sharedpreference depending the position of the view i am working?

Comment: my snippet will allow you to iterate through all your preferences. You could retrieve all your preferences outside of the adapter using prefs.getAll(), transform that Map into a Array and access single items using the position int of your adapter... so is this the use case you are confronted with? (showing all preference key/value pairs in a list?)

Comment: But i don't know how to put this code in the getView function of the adapter.

Comment: In that case you should start from scratch on how to implement lists and adapters: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html the MySimpleArrayAdapter example may give you a hint on how to map this onto your situation